# Display Confirmation Popup in Odoo

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-15

How can I display a confirmation popup in **Odoo15** through code and get the result if confirmed (true) or not confirmed(false) and continue my python code based on this result. I want to be able to show this dialog whenever i want through any python function. I don't want to use wizard since Wizard it can only be called through return. and i don't want the **button confirm=''** in the xml, i want to call the dialog through python code and get the result if confirmed or not to continue my python code.

Wizard blocks the code, since it returns the wizard, i tried Js2py module in which i call a javascript function from python but it couldn't happen since js2py gave error on require('') function in javascrript.

Comment: You can see the example of CRM **WON** or you can make a widget

Comment: i didn't understand your comment, could you please specify which model or the name of widget.

Comment: See this code in **CRM** module `action_set_won_rainbowman` for example

Comment: it doesn't show a confirmation popup, it returns a message only, i need to get if confrimed or not to proceed

Comment: Than I guess wizard is the only option

Comment: wizard can be called only at the end of the function, without getting the result if confirmed or not

Comment: You can return the wizard and can Perform the rest of the confirm action on the confirm click of the wizard.

Comment: I will add the answer for you with example

Comment: Check the OCA [multi_step_wizard](https://github.com/OCA/server-ux/tree/15.0/multi_step_wizard) module

Comment: @Kenly i didn't understand what does this addon do!

Answer (score 0):

Example py for wizard

```
class TestModelWizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name =  'salesperson.bulkassign'
    
    name = fields.Char(related = 'users.name')
    users = fields.Many2one("res.users")
    def action_apply(self):
        #perform your confirm action here
```

Example XML for wizard

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="wizard_with_step_form">
            <field name="name">wizard_with_step.form</field>
            <field name="model">salesperson.bulkassign</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Wizard with step" version="7.0">

                    <group >

                        <field name="users" widget="one2many_list" nolabel="1"  >

                            <tree editable="bottom" create="false" delete="false" no_create_edit="1" edit="false">

                                <field name="name" readonly="1"/>
                            </tree>
                        </field>
                    </group>
                    <footer >

                        <button name="action_apply" string="Action Confirm" type="object"/>
                    </footer>

                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Example py where you will call the wizard

```
def action_open_wizard(self):
    
        users = self.env["res.users"].search([])
        dic = []
        for i in users:
            if i.has_group('sales_team.group_sale_salesman'):
                i.check_box = False
                dic.append(i.id)
        #if your condition for calling wizard
        return {

            'name': _('Salesperson Bulk Assign Lead'),
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_model': 'salesperson.bulkassign',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_id': self.id,
            'context':{"default_users":dic,"default_crm":self.env.context.get('active_ids')} # you can pass the values here in the wizard,
            'target': 'new'
        }
        else:
            #what ever you want to do if not want to call Wizard
```